# PROLOG exercise with constraints

Tags: prolog, constraints, clpfd

I was doing this prolog exercise with constraints where each of the subfunctions that i did seems to work correctly but when i run the whole program it doesn't accept any solution for some reason.

We are given a predicate `sequence(+Number, -Sequence, -Cost)` where `Sequence` is a list with numbers from 0 to 3, where each of them appear `Number` times (for example, `sequence(2, [2,0,2,0,1,3,1,3], Cost)` would be valid, since each digit from 0 to 3 appears exactly 2 times.

The `Cost` is represented in this table, `costTable(X,Y,Price)`, where `X,Y` are two consecutive numbers in the `Sequence`, and the `Price` is how much it costs to go from X to Y. There are only the possibilities in this table, so where [..,2,0,...] would be valid, [...,2,3,...] is not, since there isn't any line in the table with the values (2,3,_).  The final Cost is the sum of all the Prices (for example: (2, [2,0,2,0,1,3,1,3], 15)). The ideal solution would minimize the total cost.

```
costTable(0,1,3).
costTable(0,2,3).
costTable(0,3,2).
costTable(1,3,1).
costTable(2,0,1).
costTable(2,1,4).
costTable(3,1,5).
costTable(3,3,2).
```

I did the following code:

```
sequence(Number, Sequence, Cost):-
    Length is 4*Number,
    length(Sequence,Length),
    domain(Sequence,0,3),

    checkNumber(Number,Sequence),
    cost(Sequence,Cost),

    labeling([minimize(Cost)],Sequence).


checkNumber(Number,Sequence):-
    count(0,Number,Sequence),
    count(1,Number,Sequence),
    count(2,Number,Sequence),
    count(3,Number,Sequence).

count(N,XTimes,List):-
    delete(List,N,NewList),
    length(NewList,NewLength),
    length(List,Length),
    NewLength #= Length-XTimes.

cost([_|[]],0).
cost([X,Y|Sequence],TotalCost):-
    costTable(X,Y,Cost),
    cost([Y|Sequence],NewCost),
    NewCost #= TotalCost-Cost.
```

Where `checkNumber` (that calls `count`) makes sure that the `Sequence` has each number from 0 to 3 appearing `Number` of times and `cost` calculates the total cost of the sequence.

I tested each of the functions sepparately and they all worked correctly, but when i run the program with the predicate `sequence(2,Sequence,Cost)` it simply returns no. I tracked it and it stops on the first iteration of count, on the last line (NewLength #= Length-XTimes), but I don't see why.

My exam is tomorrow and I would really appreciate if anyone could help me here, ty in advance! :)